# center align (V & H) a div with an img in a parent div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to align both an image and a div (horizontally and vertically centerd) inside parent div, but I can not, I have been trying to do it for 2 days. I am using bootstrap 4, HTML5, CSS3

**Images somehow do not show in the code snippet**

```html
<!-- Welcome Area -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="background-image: url(assets/images/main-img.jpg);">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center">
        <img src="assets/images/auscene-icon-buttons-12-t.png" class="img-responsive img-fluid" id="welcome-area-img" style="visibility: hidden;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Welcome Area -->

<!--  Main area  -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row pt-4 pb-4 mb-5 px-0">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 px-0 text-center" style="width: 10% !important;" id="show-last-news-title">
      <img src="assets/images/auscene_icon_button_01_Y9u_icon.ico" class="img-responsive img-fluid pt-4" id="auscene-image-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 px-0 text-center" style="width: 10% !important;" id="show-last-how-to-title">
      <img src="assets/images/auscene_icon_button_02_xYm_icon.ico" class="img-responsive img-fluid pt-4" id="auscene-image-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8 col-md-push-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 px-0" style="width: 60% !important;">
      <h1 class="text-left" style="font-size:3.5rem; color:#5acfc2; font-family:LouisGeorgeCafe;" id="welcome-area-title">Issue #01
      </h1>
      <h1 class="text-left" style="font-size:2rem; font-family:LouisGeorgeCafe;" id="welcome-area-subtitle"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 px-0 text-center" style="width: 10% !important;" id="show-last-guide-to-aucians-title">
      <img src="assets/images/auscene_icon_button_03_ClJ_icon.ico" class="img-responsive img-fluid pt-4" id="auscene-image-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 px-0 text-center" style="width: 10% !important;" id="show-last-in-depth-title">
      <img src="assets/images/auscene_icon_button_04_JP2_icon.ico" class="img-responsive img-fluid pt-4" id="auscene-image-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Main area -->
```

**Updated After solving the problem of not being able to align an image dead center overlaps the another, now the div takes automatically height of 20px instead of div background image's height**

Comment: please provide links to images that will render, otherwise it is impossible to help you. 
Describe **how** would you like to align them. Draw effect that you would like to achieve in paint and post it in your question or something like that, so we know what you want.

Comment: Image 1 in parent div will be 1820px X 530px (or more in width) image 2 - inside inner div- is 269px X 259px, is this okay? As i can not share the images. I want image 2 (enclosed inner div) to be dead center horizontally and vertically of image 1

Comment: How do you want them to be aligned?

Comment: Image 2 (enclosed in outer div) center align horizontal and vertical over image 1

Comment: I’d suggest you checkout CSS Flexbox, it’s great for centring.

Comment: For future readers, if anyone can help me edit the question to make it better, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you find the desired effect by use of latest Bootstrap and additional styling. Please note that this also rectifies the inconsistencies you have in your code example with the proper headers, image links and bootstrap classes.

I have placed styling inline but you can move these to a separate file if you want.

The container is set to 100% of the view height in order to center the large image (the containing row) vertically.
The smaller image is vertically aligned by the calc function where we place the image 50% minus half the image height absolutely from the top (you'll have to take this into consideration if you add the @media ref below).

Please note that both images are responsive but since the smaller image maintains its original size for longer before resizing it looks like it's bigger than the background image on smaller devices.
You can alter this with the @media rule or with more advanced CSS but that's outside of the scope of your question.

(Consider using a background image instead as Ng-Sek-Long suggests)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <title>Centered images</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- Welcome area -->
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="position: relative;">
              <img src="https://www.gruberreisen.at/fileadmin/redakteure/Website/slider/Header_Startseite1.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
              <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: calc(50% - 132px); width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/269x265/ccc.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code snippet below for an example:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}

.img-responsive {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: @field-border-radius;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}

.icon {
  width: 175px;
  height: 125px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<!-- Welcome Area -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 container">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg" class="img-responsive img-fluid" />
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center overlay">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x125" class="img-responsive img-fluid icon" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Welcome Area -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for to align the both `div` and `img` to center you can add `text-center` to the parent element as well as to align left add `text-left` and for right `text-right`. But since you are having bootstrap `col` in your `div` it will have the padding when you set `right` or `left`. You need to write `padding-left:0` or `padding-right:0` according to the alignment.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Welcome Area -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300" class="img-responsive img-fluid" />
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300?x" class="img-responsive img-fluid" style="z-index: auto;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for them to keep in both side next to one , you need to change your HTML DOM like this.
`col-**-12` which means takes the `width:100%`. If you want your child next to one your to give each child a 50% of the width. So you need to change it it `col-**-6` which gives the 50% of width.According to the logic now your parent is row and it has 2 `div` elements which are childs and having `col-**-6` for both. And inside they have the `img`. If you feel the padding is unnecessary to you, so you can add `padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;` to the element who have the class `col-**`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Welcome Area -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 parent">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300" class="img-responsive img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300?x" class="img-responsive img-fluid" style="z-index: auto;" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to keep your img inside the larger one you need to set the element to `position:absolute` which make your element to non identifiable by html. Now you can position it as you wanted.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent>img {
  height: 530px;
  width: 1820px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.inner-child {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.inner-child>img {
  height: 269px;
  width: 259px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Welcome Area -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 parent">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300" class="img-responsive img-fluid" />
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 inner-child">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300?x" class="img-responsive img-fluid" style="z-index: auto;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to align image 2 (enclosed inside inner/2nd div) horizontally and vertically centered on image 1 (enclosed in outer div)

Comment: Now checkout the answer @ElSheikh

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> Image 1 in parent div will be 1820px X 530px (or more in width) image 2 - inside inner div- is 269px X 259px,

Seems like this is what you want, a simple css will be much better than trying to use bootstrap to do the job.

```css
.outter-div {
  width: 1820px;
  height: 530px;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1820x530");
}
.inner-img {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outter-div">
        <img class="inner-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/269x259">
    </div>
```

Comment: I followed your lead, and it worked but the outer div shrinks in height to like 20px maximum not the image height of 560px, is there anyway we can handle it?

Comment: Hmm... Did you mean my answer is ok on it's own, but when combine with your entire page it will shrinks down to 20px in height? If so please also provide your entire page, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Can I send you the HTML code on your email? or re edit my question?

Comment: Re-edit is the way to go, since you also want other to have a chance to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use:

```
.v-center {
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The rest of the positioning can be done with Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters mvh-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1860x530" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="text-center position-absolute v-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/269x265/444" class="img-fluid" style="z-index: auto;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/umBZgxLzEN

Note: Make sure you [follow the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/). The `-xs` infix no longer exist, and there shouldn't be `col` directly in other `col`.

Comment: Will the code you provided work smoothly on different layouts/mobile screens? It is not supported anymore the xs col? And what do you mean with there should not be col in another?